# NodeJS app deployment to Azure linux server

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm trying to deploy my NodeJS app in Azure Ubuntu 20.04 Linux server, and gets the following error when trying to run the app.

Any ideas?

```
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Invalid status code <403>".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

It doesn't happen when trying to so locally in my workstation and I can't find the function which causes this issue as it's not mentioned.

Comment: Can you improvise your question for better understanding. Have you added a `.catch()` block to handle the error.

Comment: That's exactyly the point, I have no idea where should I do that....

Comment: Can you provide the code which you tried for better understanding the error.

Answer (score 0):

- There is an unhandled promise rejection in the code. This can occur when a promise is rejected but there is no `.catch()` block to handle the rejection.
- By adding a `.catch()` block to the promise chain or using a `try-catch` block within an async function and catch any errors that occur during the execution of the code and handle them appropriately.

Below is an sample of `.catch()` If a rejection occurs, the error message is logged to the console.

```js
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // Do some async work
  reject(new Error('Something went wrong'));
});

myPromise
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```

- `try-catch` block is used to catch any errors that occur in the `myAsyncFunction` function.

```js
async function myAsyncFunction() {
  try {
    // Do some async work
    throw new Error('Something went wrong');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}

myAsyncFunction();
```